# Computing and plotting pdf of U as a function of two uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: matlab, pdf, random, distribution

I am working on a joint pdf problem in which the random variable

```
U = sqrt(X^2+Y^2)
```

`X` and `Y` are uniformly distributed over `(-2,2)`. I want to plot joint pdf of `X` and `Y`. Then compute pdf of `U` and plot it as well. I am using matlab R2011a, and so far, I have come up with the following code. On running the code I got an error message

```
Undefined function or method 'makedist' for input arguement type 'char'.
```

I found out that makedist is not on 2011 version. So I tried using

```
a=-2;
b=2;
X=a+(b-a)*rand(-10,10);
Y= a+(b-a)*rand(-10,10).
```

However, I am not sure how to compute pdfs of `X` and `Y`, and then joint pdf of `XY` from this. Any help, partial or holistic, is appreciated.

Here is the matlab code for the problem

```
%% Create distribution objects for X~U(-2,2) and Y~U(-2,2)

pdx=makedist('Uniform','lower',-2,'upper',2);

pdy=makedist('Uniform','lower',-2,'upper',2);

%Compute the pfs

x_ref=-10:1:10;

y_ref=-10:1:10;

pdf_x=pdf(pdx,x_ref);

pdf_y=pdf(pdy,y_ref);

% Plot the pdfs

figure 1;

stairs(x_ref,pdf_x,'g','Linewidth',2);

hold on;

stairs(y_ref,pdf_y,'r','Linewidth',2);
ylim([0 1.5]);

hold off;

% Joint pdf of x and Y

pdfXY=pdf_x*pdf_y;
figure 2;

plot(pdfXY);

%CDF and PDF of U 

U=sqrt(X^2+Y^2);

Umin=0;

Umax=sqrt(b^2+b^2);

a=lower;

b=upper;

x=sqrt(U^2-Y^2);

xmin=0;

xmax=x;

ymin=0;

ymax=U;

Ucdf=integral2(pdfXY,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax);

% plot CDF of U

figure 3;

plot(Ucdf)
```

---

*I am just looking to plot the regions than for any specific sample set. `X` and `Y` are continuous independent uniform random variables.*

Comment: Do you want the _theoretical_ joint pdf or an _empirical_ joint pdf obtained from a set of sample values?

Comment: Theoretical, and I assumed makedist was the way to go for it.

Answer (score 0):

As your `x` and `y` are [independent at random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29#For_random_variables), the theoretical joint distribution is just a product of the two

```
P(x,y) = P(x)*P(y)
```

In terms of MATLAB code, you may think of `x` and `y` running along two different dimensions:

```
N = 10; %// think of a probability mass function over N points

x = linspace(-2,2, N);
y = linspace(-2,2, N)';

Px = ones(N,1)./N;
Py = ones(1,10)./N;

%// Then the joint will be:
Jxy = bsxfun(@times, Px , Py);

figure
pcolor(x,y,Jxy)
```

You can now plug whatever distribution you like, if they are independent for `Px` and `Py`, and it will work

Comment: Thank you Dima Lituiev, but this will be for discrete X and Y, right?

Comment: in computer, you ever have to discretise things. What you did in your example, is mixing of simulation and theory. For simulation, you can generate continuously random variables. However, to represent a theoretical pdf (e.g. for plotting), you need to discretise your domain. Alternatively, you may want to write a function, which will describe pdf for a continuous variable.

Comment: I get it. Yeah, I actually want pdf for continuous variable.

Comment: My question for the first part is this: Does my code with make dist create pdfs of X and Y, and plot the joint pdf of XY in newer versions of matlab? Can anybody confirm this for me, as I am getting undefined function error. I am also trying to fix this by modifying my code

Comment: then put it clearly into your question above. i have an earlier version of MATLAB, so no idea. But if your version does not support it, what is the point of doing it?